# Duplicate records when returning search results with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that has several movie clips and users can search for specific topics etc... I'm using Ajax to handle pagination so that users can make a search query and scroll to view more results (similar to twitter).

The issue is when a user searches for i.e. "Funny" a bunch of records will come up and as the user scrolls down Ajax will load duplicates of the records a long with new records.

Here's the code:

```
if $('.pagination').length
  $(window).scroll ->
    url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
    if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
      $('.loader').removeClass('hidden')
      $.getScript(url)
  $(window).scroll()
```

Here's an screenshot [image: Example]

How can I prevent rails from duplicating records in this case? I've tried uniq and several other methods to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to explain your problem a bit more. Could this be an issue of the pagination elements not being updated?

Comment: so, i type in "funny" for example and it returns lets say 10 results then i scroll down and u get the loading symbol and there's now more results however, there's duplicate results of the former along with new results,  i've tried #uniq and a bunch of rails functions aren't helping which leaves me to believe it's an js issue. the queries are loaded through sphinx, and additional results are displayed with ajax but there is duplicate rendering. when I scroll down and new results are loaded I'd like them to be "new" here's some additional code: https://gist.github.com/pblogs/e202ee1f03339ba977ec